# static method help needed

Tags: c#

I've a class similar to one below:

```
namespace BLL {
 public partial class SomeClass
 {

   public void Save(string xmlFile){
    //Body
   }
   public static Person Parse(string xml)
   {
       //Body
   }
  }
 }
```

Problem:
 I can call Save method by creating an instance of SomeClass. However I can't access the Parse method from instance of SomeClass. I also tried SomeClass.Parse, still no luck.
 If I do BLL.SomeClass.Parse then I can only access that Parase Method.

Could anyone please help me out what's happening on above scenario? Is it only possible to access static method from namaspace.class.methodname?

Thanks.

Comment: `SomeClass.Parse()` should work, or even `Parse()` if you are calling from within that class. Can you show the code where you are trying to call it from?

Comment: `Parse()` is a static method.  You call static methods using `ClassName.MethodName()`.  In your case, `SomeClass.Parse("...")`.  that is of course, assuming that the namespace is in scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the namespace in a using, you should be able to do SomeClass.Parse. Otherwise you have to do BLL.SomeClass.Parse. And it is not possible to call static functions from an instance object.

Answer (score 0):

To call parse, you have to call as: SomeClass.Parse("") you don't need an instance. If you don't want to explicitly name your namespace, then just add a "using BLL;"
Further Reading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645629(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is true that you can not call a static method on an instance of a class. You must use the class name (like `BLL.SomeClass.Parse`). That doesn't mean you can't also access Save from an instance (like `instanceOfSomeClass.Save(...)`)